# Does anyone know how to "group" turtle objects together so that they can be operated as one single item?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to understand if we can group two or more turtle objects together so that they can behave as one single unit/item.

I tried this code:

But I have no idea how to write the create_group() function

```
def snake_body():
    global snake
    for i in range(3):
        new_turtle = Turtle("square")
        new_turtle.color("yellow")
        new_turtle.setx(i * 20)
        snake.append(new_turtle)

def snake_group():
    #canvas = screen.getcanvas()
    group_1 = create_group(snake) #this function will make the snake item in one group. I want to use group_1 to now work as a unit


snake_body()
snake_group()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class to group the different `Turtle` objects together. From the name of your variables, I guess you want to write a simple snake game (and please do correct me if I'm mistaken).

I wrote a rough sketch for a class Snake, see below:

```py
import turtle
import time


class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body = []
        self.direction = (20, 0)
        for i in range(3):
            new_turtle = turtle.Turtle("square")
            new_turtle.color("yellow")
            new_turtle.setx(i * 20)
            self.body.append(new_turtle)

    def move(self):
        for b in self.body:
            b.setpos(b.pos() + self.direction)


# example usage
snake = Snake()
for i in range(20):
    snake.move()
    time.sleep(.5)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

There's really much room for improvement. In the example, the snake will do some wonky movement to the right and trail a line (it was never switched off). Of course, there's no means of control and no collision detection. Also, you will have to rework the `move` method to do the typical snake-like trailing motion.

You will have to flesh out the class yourself. The nice thing about this design is that you have all your `Turtle`s grouped together and can control them as one by adding new methods to `Snake`.